# newline and dash not working correctly in jinja

Tags: python, python-2.7, yaml, jinja2, removing-whitespace

How could I generate the expected output ? Thanks

## jinja template

```
{%- for field in fields -%}

-
  name: {{field}}
  type: string



{%- endfor -%}
```

## output

```
-
  name: operating revenue
  type: string-
  name: gross operating profit
  type: string-
```

## expected output

```
-
  name: operating revenue
  type: string
-
  name: gross operating profit
  type: string
```

## code

```
from jinja2 import Template

fields = ["operating revenue", "gross operating profit", "EBITDA", "operating profit after depreciation", "EBIT", "date"]
template_file = open('./fields_template.jinja2').read()
template = Template(template_file)
html_rendered = template.render(fields=fields)
print(html_rendered)
```

Comment: THanks your solution still not working for me, please check it https://gist.github.com/poc7667/717bb260ed959184cdbf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `-` removes all whitespace between *that side* of the Jinja tag and the first character. You are using `-` on the 'inside' of the tags, so whitespace is removed up to the `-` character and after the word `string`, joining up the two. Remove one or the other.

You could remove the extra newlines at the start and end of your text for example, and remove the `-` from the inside side of the opening tag:

```
{%- for field in fields %}
-
  name: {{field}}
  type: string
{%- endfor -%}
```

Demo:

```
>>> from jinja2 import Template
>>> fields = ["operating revenue", "gross operating profit", "EBITDA", "operating profit after depreciation", "EBIT", "date"]
>>> template_file = '''\
... {%- for field in fields %}
... -
...   name: {{field}}
...   type: string
... {%- endfor -%}
... '''
>>> template = Template(template_file)
>>> html_rendered = template.render(fields=fields)
>>> print(html_rendered)

-
  name: operating revenue
  type: string
-
  name: gross operating profit
  type: string
-
  name: EBITDA
  type: string
-
  name: operating profit after depreciation
  type: string
-
  name: EBIT
  type: string
-
  name: date
  type: string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress rendering of the below lines:

```
<% for ... %>
<% endfor %>
<% if ... %>
<% endif %>
```

by setting trim_blocks=True and lstrip_blocks=True in your jinja2 environment per [their docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#whitespace-control). See your updated code below:

```
from jinja2 import Template

fields = ["operating revenue", "gross operating profit", "EBITDA", "operating profit after depreciation", "EBIT", "date"]
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('.'), trim_blocks=True, lstrip_blocks=True)

html_rendered = jinja_env.get_template('fields_template.jinja2').render(fields=fields)
print(html_rendered)
```

Edit your template file to be (the intuitive):

```
{% for field in fields %}
-
  name: {{field}}
  type: string
{% endfor %}
```