# Python pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: python, mysql

pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test-db`.* TO `test-user`' at line 1")

Getting above python error, but when I execute the query from workbench its executing perfectly fine

New to python here

Comment: Show complete code which executes this statement - we cannot predict it.

Comment: The user name should have an @ in it, and user and host part should be quoted using regular single quotes, not backticks. E.g. 

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test-db`.* TO 'test-user'@'localhost';

Comment: This is not a python error, this is a mysql error. Is there any sql statement before the grant one?

Comment: Thanks @All, sorry the issue was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232830/newline-and-dash-not-working-correctly-in-jinja

jinja is not separting the queries and due to that it was throwing the error my bad